# Preventing broken NFS connection from freezing the client system

Tags: nfs

We have an NFS 4 share, sharing a volume between a number of servers (NFS server, and clients all Debian 8).  We have had some issues recently where network outages would freeze the client systems.

Our NFS options were minimal, just `rw` (and so the defaults `hard`, `fg`, etc).

I'm now experimenting with these options, but am not getting the behaviour I expect:
 `rw,soft,bg,retrans=6,timeo=150`

(I've increased the retrans to offset some of the soft risk)

The procedure I'm following to test is :

- Boot machine
- `cd` to `/mnt/mountpoint`
- Verify NFS connection ok
- `cd /`
- kill network `ifdown eth0`
- `cd` to `/mnt/mountpoint`
- `ls`

*At this point the command line freezes, and I can't interupt it.*  After some time the message 'nfs: server [servername] not responding, timed out`, which seems to repeat once a minute (indefinately).

What I would like/expect to happen for the operation to fail, and return control.

**Please could someone tell me where I'm going wrong with these settings?**

(PS: I also tried mounting with autofs, but saw similar behaviour)

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `soft` under any circumstances. It allows data to be [discarded on error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTG2D_6.4.0/com.ibm.itsm.client.doc/c_bac_nfshsmounts.html). Instead I'd suggest `hard,intr`.

Comment: @roaima - Thanks.  That opinion seems to be very prevalent on the web :) Trouble is the current situation we have with `hard` is just as bad for us (systems dying and staying dead until rebooted). `intr` is not supported in NFS4 according to man.

Comment: (Correction, it seems `intr` it's supported by NFS4, but not by kernels > 2.6.25)

Comment: I think that the thing that differs from the 'standard' answers is that you're changing current working directory to the mount point.  Do you get the same behaviour without the `cd`, but instead doing `ls /mnt/mountpoint`?  It's possible that after the `ls` fails, your shell is attempting filesystem operations dependent on PWD.  (Even worse, if you were foolish enough to put `.` in your `$PATH`)

Answer (score 4):

`intr` should allow for you to get control again when you hit `^C`, but usually not immediately.

> ```
>    intr           If an NFS file operation has a major timeout and it is hard mounted, then allow signals to interupt the
>                   file  operation  and cause it to return EINTR to the calling program.  The default is to not allow file
>                   operations to be interrupted.
> ```

As you say, expectations are the problem here.  Network problems can be temporary, but failing an operation is permanent.  So most operations default to simply blocking until the operation completes.

This is the standard answer, but looking at a current man page I see this:

> ```
>                   The  intr / nointr mount option is deprecated after ker-
>                   nel 2.6.25.  Only SIGKILL can interrupt  a  pending  NFS
>                   operation on these kernels, and if specified, this mount
>                   option is ignored  to  provide  backwards  compatibility
>                   with older kernels.
> ```

So it doesn't appear to me to be a NFS3/NFS4 issue, but a decision about how `intr` works.  So you should be able to `KILL` the process, but that may not give you much utility.

I was unable to find the discussion about why the option was removed.  Can you kill -KILL your process?

Comment: Thanks, but according to man `intr` is supported by nfs 2/3 but not 4.

Comment: @UpTheCreek, I don't understand why that would be.  I don't have a debian system here but it's explicitly mentioned as available.  Have you tried it?  "intr   This will allow NFS4 operations (on hard mounts) to be interrupted while waiting for a response from the server."

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, and it didn't seem to have any effect.  Man says it's ignored in recent kernel versions.

Comment: It is not possible to KILL a process because the entire system freezes. No commands can be issued in my experience. (Although it might be possible to SSH into such a frozen machine in some cases.)

Answer (score 3):

Some of my answer is opinion, based on experience. Where I have facts I will (try to remember to) link to them.

1. NFS 4 is considered an [improvement](http://www.iaps.com/NFSv4-new-features.html) over versions 2 and 3. However, I've not yet seen a strong use case for needing the improvements. Perhaps that's because I aim to export filesystems to Windows clients with Samba and to Unix/Linux clients with NFS.
2. I wouldn't recommend `soft` under almost any circumstances. It allows data to be [discarded on error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTG2D_6.4.0/com.ibm.itsm.client.doc/c_bac_nfshsmounts.html). Instead I'd suggest `hard,intr`.
3. As you point out, `intr` isn't valid for NFS 4, but it seems that this is a [kernel change](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs) rather than an NFS one.
4. The NFS Automounter (`autofs`) works well for my use cases with NFS versions 2 and 3, and manages to help protect my client systems from server failure by mounting the NFS filesystems only while they are required.

My suggestion to you would be to consider moving from NFS 4 to NFS 3 and see if that helps your particular use case. Don't think of it as a downgrade.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not able to switch to NFS3, and even if I were, as you say, `intr` is not supported on recent kernel versions.

Comment: Ah yeah looks like `intr` *is* supported in NFS4 (it's listed in both the 2/3 only options *and* the 4 only options in man, which is a bit confusing), but just not supported in recently kernel versions.

Comment: "I wouldn't recommend soft under any circumstances" - really? In my case, I have a busy web server that mounts an images directory. If the images host goes down and we use `hard`, the whole website goes down. If we use `soft`, we might possibly get a few broken images (though our caching system mitigates this almost completely). The risk of `soft` allowing file corruption really isn't that much of a big deal. I'd much rather have one corrupt image file than a site down!

Comment: @DougMcLean having also been in a similar situation (busy web farm, image servers, NFS...) I would say it's a somewhat specialised case. If my image servers had been as unreliable I suspect I might well have settled for `soft` as an acceptable solution. Answer modified from "never" to "almost never". Thanks!

Comment: If my memory is correct, this system freeze problem was also present in NFS v3.