# Where are NFS defaults specified?

Tags: nfs

In regards to: [Preventing broken NFS connection from freezing the client system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267138/preventing-broken-nfs-connection-from-freezing-the-client-system).

My system runs SLES 11.4 and I use NFS v3.

In my `/etc/fstab` file on an NFS client system I have:

```
mastersystem:/masterdata  /data  nfs defaults 0 0
```

Can someone tell me how I can find out what the **defaults** are? I'm looking to find where in the filesystem it says to use whatever options as default from the listing shown by doing a `man nfs`?

Comment: `man nfs` should give you plenty of details, or http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs

Comment: both of those tell me all the options i can use, but what i am asking is when i specify **defaults** in my `/etc/fstab` file, what specific options make up the **defaults** list.  This i cannot find.

Comment: It _does_ explain, but you have to read; eg _soft / hard
 ...  If neither option is specified (or if the hard option is specified), NFS requests are retried indefinitely._  so we can tell that "hard" is the default for that one option.  You need to read the whole page to see what the default values are for each option.

Comment: sorry let me rephrase,  I understand what the values are as reported by doing man nfs, but i looking to find if and where those values actually reside.  for instance I have `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` where i can specify port numbers for statd, mountd, and lockd.  Wondering if there is a similar file somewhere under /etc/ where is says nfs_defaults=hard,timeout=600, and so on.

Comment: No such file in `/etc`, no.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [man fstab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html)

> Basic filesystem-independent options are:
>
> **defaults**
> use  default  options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.

This defines the settings for the `defaults` keyword.

NFS has its own (additional) set of defaults that are implied unless you tell it otherwise. An example of this is `hard` vs `soft`, where `hard` is the implied value unless you specify `soft`. These are not enumerated clearly anywhere that I know of, but must be gleaned (quite possibly painfully slowly) from the [nfs(5) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs).

Comment: looking to find a file similar to `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` that will have something in it like `nfs_defaults=hard, timeout=600, retrans=3...... and so on` corresponding to all those values that are said to be default per the man page or linux.die.net.   The default value of **600** for timeout, that number of **600** has to be specified somewhere in the system and i'm looking to find where and if i can edit it.

Comment: so far i have only found `/proc/mounts` where it has `mastersystem:/masterdata /data nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2`   so even though i'm using `nfs defaults` in `/etc/fstab` my retrans is not 3.

Comment: @Ron it's probably embedded in the program code