# How to automatically mount NFS share from another system automatically at boot?

Tags: debian, nfs, fstab

I use the following command to mount an NFS share from another system on Debian:

`sudo mount hypercube.home:/volume1/ /mnt/hypercube/`

But this does not persist after boot. I believe I need to add something to `fstab` but the syntax is probably different and I'm not sure what's the correct syntax for NFS shares.

How can I find out the correct mount syntax and parameters to mount this share automatically at boot on my Debian system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
hypercube.home:/volume1 /mnt/hypercube nfs4 defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

If the target system isn’t always on, you might like to check the options described in [Debian NFS wait too long when the other Debian is turned off](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466070/86440) in addition to the above.

Comment: That's it, but you have a typo `nsf` instead of `nfs`, took me a while before I noticed it. Thanks.